# German stock exchange, ETR vs FRA

Tags: stocks, stock-exchanges, germany, google-finance

I am looking at the **BMW stock** for instance in google finance.

Presented are two tickers:

**ETR:BMW**
https://www.google.com/finance?q=ETR%3ABMW&ei=uNGuU-CSGeP3wAPw-IC4Cg

and

**FRA:BMW**
https://www.google.com/finance?q=FRA%3ABMW&ei=vdGuU8mgF6qpwAPCsoHQCQ

There is a price difference since 2009. The FRA has grown about 55% but the ETR has **grown around 80%**.

Now, I own BMW stock, but I can't really see in my terminal which one I actually own.

My understanding is that **ETR** is a trading system, called **XETRA** while the old one, FRA referes to the price on the Frankfurt Stock Exchange.

I still can't understand why there **is a price discrepancancy**.

Which one is the preferred stock to own, and why?

Answer (score 10):

> I still can't understand why there is a price discrepancancy.

There isn't. It's the same stock and price differences between such major exchanges will always be minimal.

I think you simply haven't paid attention to the date range. It seems Google finance only has data for FRA:BMW reaching back to 2011, so if you try to look at the development of your investment since 2009, you're not getting comparable data.

Comment: Ok, I think you are right. I must have been comparing FRA: BMW3 when I had them both in one graph.

Thanks for clarifying though!

Comment: Please would you mark this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

I stumbled on the same discrepancy, and was puzzled by a significant difference between the two prices on ETR and FRA. For example, today is Sunday, and google shows the following closing prices for DAI.

**FRA:DAI**:

```
Date            Open    High    Low     Close   Volume
Nov 20, 2015    78.55   79.50   78.50   79.36   8,910
```

**ETR:DAI**:

```
Date            Open    High    Low     Close   Volume
Nov 20, 2015    79.16   79.60   78.60   79.25   3,076,967
```

So it looks like there are indeed two different exchanges trading at different prices.

Now, the important value here, is the last column (`Volume`). According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frankfurt_Stock_Exchange), the trading on Frankfort Stock Exchange is done today *exclusively* via Xetra platform, thus the volume on **ETR:DAI** is much more important than on **FRA:DAI**.

Obviously, they Wikipedia is not 100% accurate, i.e. not *all* trading is done electronically via Xetra. According to their web-page, Frankfort exchange has a [**Specialist Trading on Frankfurt Floor**](http://www.boerse-frankfurt.de/en/basics+overview/marketplaces/trading+hours) service which has slightly different trading hours.

I suspect what Google and Yahoo show as Frankfort exchange is this *manual* trading via a *Specialist* (opposed to Xetra *electronic* trading).

To answer your question, the stock you're having is exactly the same, meaning if you bought an **ETR:BMW** you can still sell it on **FRA** (by calling a FRA Trading Floor Specialist which will probably cost you a fee).

On the other hand, for the portfolio valuation and performance assessments you should only use **ETR:BMW** prices, because it is way more liquid, and thus better reflect the current market valuation.